# Can Sent SMS Messages have a Relationship to a Received SMS in Android?

Tags: android, sms

Is there any way to relate a received SMS to a sent SMS?  For example, an Android application that sends out a question that requires a yes/no answer.  The recipient would simply "reply" to the SMS with their answer and the original sending application would no that the answer was related to the particular question.  If it's only a single SMS message, it's easy because the sender is only waiting for a single response.  However, for example, if three questions were sent to the recipient, would it be possible to determine which message was being replied to?

My gut instinct is that it is not possible and that each SMS is essentially sent or received in isolation and without a receiving application to parse some "tag" in the original message, this would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to reply with three different responses.

Q1: Do you like ...?
Reply y1 for yes or n1 for no

Q2: What is your fav ...?
Reply y2 for yes or n2 for no

etc...